# How to fill the area between two bezier curves using dear imgui

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

How can I fill the area between two bezier curves using [dear imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui)?

I drew the curves using the ImDrawList API, like this:

```
        ImVec2 p0(10, 100); ImVec2 c1(110, 50); ImVec2 p1(210, 100);
        ImVec2 q0(10, 200); ImVec2 c2(110, 100); ImVec2 q1(210, 200);

        auto col = IM_COL32(0,255,255, 255);

        ImDrawList* draw_list = ImGui::GetWindowDrawList();

        draw_list->AddBezierCurve(p0, c1, c1, p1, col, 1.0f);
        draw_list->AddBezierCurve(q0, c2, c2, q1, col, 1.0f);

        // I can close the curves, visually, with these lines
        draw_list->AddLine(p0, q0, col, 1.0f);
        draw_list->AddLine(p1, q1, col, 1.0f);
```

Edit:

I used the stateful API to draw the path I wanted and then I called a function to fill this path. Here's the code:

```
        draw_list->PathLineTo(p0);
        draw_list->PathBezierCurveTo(c1, c1, p1);
        draw_list->PathLineTo(q1);
        draw_list->PathBezierCurveTo(c2, c2, q0);

        draw_list->PathFillConvex(col);
```

But there is something wrong as you can see:

[image: result]

The correct geometry is drawn in white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is, that filling primitives in OpenGL is only defined for *convex* primitives. A set is defined to be *convex* if for any two points inside the set you can draw a line between these points without leaving the boundaries of said set.

Dear-ImGUI mostly just passes on the translated drawing commands to OpenGL as they are, without any intermediary tesselation. … which causes the problem you see and why the filling function is has that `…Convex` part in it's name.

The solution is to either break down the non-convex shape into smaller, convex subshapes, or to use a filling method that also works for convex shapes, like the [scanline](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm) algorithm (implementation of which on a GPU is most easily done using a compute shader).

Comment: Thank you. Looking for the scanline algorithm I found an implementation using imgui: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/760.

Answer (score 2):

You need a concave fill algorithm which dear imgui doesn't provide. Generally it tends to be easier/faster to decompose your shapes into convex shapes. The general case of filling "between two beziers" is tricky because the beziers can intersect, so there can be multiple areas. If you know that they are never going to intersect and that your tangents are not too crazy, you may use various approximations. Maybe try drawing N quads where each quads links two segments of the beziers at regularly spaced interval etc. Datenwolf answers are a good starting point for the more generic answer.

I also need to comment on Datenwolf answer. Dear ImGui doesn't "passes on the translated drawing commands to OpenGL as they are" this statement doesn't make sense here, as all the triangulation is performed by imgui, and there's no concept of filling or shapes that OpenGL is aware of since it is being passed raw textured triangles only.

In theory dear imgui could provide a "PathFillConcave()" function but it hasn't been implemented and it may be costly and complex to do. The link posted above has one indeed.